Revised -100V power supply
I drew this schematic for a -100V supply in QSpice.  It seems to work as I want it to, but I wanted to get feedback on my design and suggestions if there is a better way to do this or if I made any big mistakes.
I am working on this  DC power supply for the electrostatic G1 grid of a CRT. It's extremely high impedance, but it needs to be pretty stable. I am tapping off the regulated 12V (to power the TLC555) and the 180V B+ (it's IC regulated in this unit) to power the circuit, so I'm trying to ensure that my quiescent current and total load is as low as possible. This is what I came up with and modelled in QSpice.

Mostly what I struggled with was oscillations on the output of the 555. I put in a series resistor for that.  Then there was some instability in the charge pump for which I put in an RC snubber on the NMOS. I did the 7.5V power source with a Zener because I don't have a 7.5V regulator on hand.
This is a google drive link to the qspice file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U5wIQ_1KPi8MHro_y9vMyM-_im7vaS8r/view?usp=drive_link
These are the first two posts I made about this, including someone's suggestion for the topology I used.
-100V Power Supply from +180V Source?
QSpice sim results
I revised my design based on below comment suggesting I use a lower power NPN in place of the NMOS.

I plotted the subsequent power dissipation as suggested.

If my math is correct, this is about P_avg = 9 × (15/800) ≈ 170mW, which is hopefully okay for the part and not too much a load on my 180V supply.

I think I'd try something like an MPSA42 or one of the smaller "MJE13003" parts rather than a massive 52A power MOSFET that is characterized at 10V Vgs. Check the power dissipation in the simulation.

Please post a picture of your physical layout. Be sure to segregate the 555 circuit from the HV side as much as possible. If the HV switching noise gets into the 555 circuit, you will have issues. Since you have a floating 12V/7.5 to power the 555, you only need 2 wires (MOSFET source and gate) between the 555 and HV circuit.

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany Thanks for the input. I replaced with an MJE340 in the simulation and it seems okay and looks cleaner actually. The part is 300V VCEO, 3V VCBO/VEBO, 1/2 amp. Seem like a better choice to you?

@Mattman944 Not sure how I would implement that exactly. Would it be gate to output of 555 and source to the 180V supply? I currently have the drain on 180V. Would this still work if I switched the NMOS for the NPN as suggested in the above comment?

Why are you lowering your 12V power supply down to 7.5 volts?

@MathKeepsMeBusy Because I was trying to keep the conditions of the circuit similar to the suggested example I got from the previous post I made. I guess I could keep it at 12V, but I want to isolate it from the supply to prevent it from interacting with anything upstream. Maybe I could put a diode and some filtering after it? I noticed with the 7.5V supply, the 555 circuit's timing components were interacting with the supply in my simulation, so I definitely want to avoid that.

I built a simplified version that runs at a lower voltage, it works fine. I just ordered some high voltage parts to satisfy my curiosity. I will post the results in 10 days or so.
